# Django 1.6 : Saving most fields of current object to a different table

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model A defined with bunch of fields.

Here is what I want to do:
Whenever a certain method say `x()` is called on model A, I want to create a new record in another model (say model B) with all the fields(except pk).

Here is how I thought of solving it:

1. Make model B inherit from model A. So I will get all the fields setup automatically.
2. Serialize the current object whenever `x()` is called, prune the fields that I don't need, instantiate B(**serialized_json)

This way, every time the method is called, I would have a record for it in model B with all the relevant fields stored with it. This achieves my goal.

Is there a better way of doing this? I am pretty sure there would be.

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ will be good place to ask this question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of django models signals concept:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Model1)
def replicate_model1(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    # instance will have the Model1 data which is already saved     
    model_obj = Model2(field1=instance.field1, ....)
    model_obj.save()
```

Django docs ref:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/signals/

Comment: yep, using signal is best for this scenario

Comment: This helps a lot. Didn't even know about signals.
About the model_obj = Model2(field1=instance.field1, ....) part:

Would it be more efficient to serialize, prune and create and instance if most of the fields are the same ?

Comment: @user3732361 Cool. Accept the answer, so for others it will help!

Comment: I have given something to start on. The rest depends on your project requirements, so try it out.